# jQuery Lazy Load XT - Force Image Load On Custom Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I have a custom event `switchSlideEvent` firing each time a switchSlide() method is called from a jQuery Carousel plugin with no documentation.

I am using Lazy Load XT (https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt) to lazy load images, however, the plugin only loads images on the following events `load` `orientationchange` `resize` `scroll`.

Lazy Load XT is initialized like so:

```
$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
   selector: 'img[data-original]',
   srcAttr: 'data-original',
   edgeY: 200,
   updateEvent: 'load orientationchange resize scroll switchSlideEvent'
});
```

I've tried the following solutions, but haven't had any success:

1. Pass `switchSlideEvent` to the Lazy Load XT `updateEvent` option (seen above)
2. Manually re-initialize Lazy Load XT `.on('switchSlideEvent')` like so:

I'm getting console.log events, but the carousel images "slid" into view are not loading until I scroll the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('switchSlideEvent', function(){
    console.log("custom event fired");
    $(window).lazyLoadXT();
  }); 
});
```

**QUESTION**

How can I force Lazy Load XT to load the new images when `switchSlideEvent` fires?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `switchSlide()` method of the carousel plugin, there was an `animate` method with a `complete` callback function. I added another event `$.event.trigger("switchSlideAnimateEvent")` within the `complete` callback function and adjusted my initialization code as follows:

```
$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
selector: 'img[data-original]',
srcAttr: 'data-original',
edgeY: 200,
updateEvent: 'load orientationchange resize scroll switchSlideEvent switchSlideAnimateEvent'
});
```

I removed the `$(document).on(switchSlideEvent)` handler completely as it was not necessary and the images are now loading properly.

Cheers.